# Debian Jessie won't detect new Wacom Intuos (CTL490DB)

Tags: debian, xsetwacom

I have recently installed Debian Jessie on my computer, and purchased a new Wacom Intuos tablet. I was expecting to be able to simply plug it in and use it, as I have with Wacom devices on Debian in the past, however this was not the case.

GNOME's Wacom tablet configuration tool is entirely unable to detect the tablet, as is `xsetwacom --list devices`. `/dev/wacom` does not exist.

I have tried to install `xf86-input-wacom`, [as per the debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/WacomTablets), however apt reports that the package does not exist. Additionally, `wacom-tools` is nowhere to be found, despite the WacomTablets guide suggesting that it might help in making Wacom tablets work.

**Edit:**

`lsusb -v` information about the device:

```
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 056a:033b Wacom Co., Ltd 
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x056a Wacom Co., Ltd
  idProduct          0x033b 
  bcdDevice            1.00
  iManufacturer           1 
  iProduct                2 
  iSerial                 0 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           84
    bNumInterfaces          3
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              498mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 No Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 None
      iInterface              0 
        HID Device Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType        33
          bcdHID               1.10
          bCountryCode            0 Not supported
          bNumDescriptors         1
          bDescriptorType        34 Report
          wDescriptorLength     208
         Report Descriptors: 
           ** UNAVAILABLE **
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0010  1x 16 bytes
        bInterval               2
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 No Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 None
      iInterface              0 
        HID Device Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType        33
          bcdHID               1.10
          bCountryCode            0 Not supported
          bNumDescriptors         1
          bDescriptorType        34 Report
          wDescriptorLength      38
         Report Descriptors: 
           ** UNAVAILABLE **
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               2
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        2
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Boot Interface Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol      2 Mouse
      iInterface              0 
        HID Device Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType        33
          bcdHID               1.10
          bCountryCode            0 Not supported
          bNumDescriptors         1
          bDescriptorType        34 Report
          wDescriptorLength      52
         Report Descriptors: 
           ** UNAVAILABLE **
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x83  EP 3 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               2
```

Whenever I reconnect the device, `dmesg -w` finds:

```
[ 2698.799087] usb 1-2.3: New USB device found, idVendor=056a, idProduct=033b
[ 2698.799110] usb 1-2.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 2698.799126] usb 1-2.3: Product: Intuos PS
[ 2698.799139] usb 1-2.3: Manufacturer: Wacom Co.,Ltd.
```

Comment: The Package is `xserver-xorg-input-wacom` and I think ''libwacom-common, libwacom2` Maybe helpful <http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=121320>

Comment: @Bahamut it seems that all of those packages are set to manually installed on my system, but xsetwacom still does not identify the device as a wacom tablet. (`lsusb -v`, however, identifies the device, but is only capable of identifying `idVendor 0x056a Wacom Co., Ltd` as a Human Interface Device, but it gives no other information about it.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue (same tablet, same OS) and finally could solve the problem following this guideline:

http://linuxwacom.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Input-wacom

building the kernel module for wacom from scratch - took about 10 minutes.

Comment: Thanks! (This question *is* a bit old, and I'd solved that by now, but I appreciate the help!)

Comment: Worked for Debian Stretch and Wacom Intuos CTL 4100. Thanks!